# Is there a way to containerized a normal AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, aws-lambda, containers

My AWS lambda functions have input from AWS SNS (Topic subscription) and output will go to CRUD in NoSQL Database (likewise MongoDB).

So currently I have the SNS & Lambda function setup in AWS Cloud and they are working fine. However, I would like to containerize the lambda function as well as the MongoDB database and host them on AWS EKS using Docker + Kubernetes service. (So the functions will be a Docker image)

I am totally new to this container thing and I searched online though I could not found any that mentions how to containerized AWS Lambda Functions.

Is this possible? If it is what are the ways to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker environment for AWS lambda function already exist and it is [lambci/lambda](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/). So if you want to run/test your functions locally, this is the tool normally used for that:

> A sandboxed local environment that **replicates the live AWS Lambda environment almost identically** – including installed software and libraries, file structure and permissions, environment variables, context objects and behaviors – even the user and running process are the same.

Since its open-sourced, you can also modify it if it does not suit your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I am not looking to run/test the function locally though. I want to create a docker image with my lambda function and eventually host on AWS EKS using Kubernetes, but I might found a way using the link you provided! I will try on what that link says, thanks!

Comment: @Corene You can create your docker image from the lambda image I linked.

Comment: Yup I saw that, I will follow the link to do that, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Marchin - for local testing a Lambda [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) is a better approach. Also, look at Knative for running functions (not Lambda) on K8S,

Answer (score 0):

Lambda already uses [Firecracker](https://firecracker-microvm.github.io/) a microVM technology. So, not really sure why it's required to create a container out of Lambda.

The beauty of Lambda/Serverless is to simply write the function code and forget about the rest. If it's all about more control, then look at [Knative](https://knative.dev/) which runs on top of K8S.

Comment: Its actually that we try to make it less dependent on platform. Because the exactly same app was previously a Azure Function App, now we want to migrate to AWS Lambda Function, and we want to host all of the apps + database on Docker to decrease the dependance to platform. Not sure this is ideal tho haha

Comment: Main purpose of K8S and Knative it to make it platform independent. The function created using these is Cloud agnostic.